# How to write only non existing records to Cosmos DB from using Azure Cosmos DB Spark?

Tags: azure, apache-spark, azure-cosmosdb, databricks, azure-databricks

I am using Databricks which writes the data from CSV file to Cosmos DB using Spark Connector. Now my Cosmos DB already contains few records, so when I run Databricks Notebooks, it should write only the records which doesn't exist in DB.
I tried with SaveMode.Ignore but doesn't help.

```
df.write.mode(SaveMode.Ignore).cosmosDB(writeConfig)
```

Now ideally, SaveMode.Ignore should skip over the existing records and write the only ones which doesn't exist in DB but it is not happening.

It would be a great help if anyone has suggestions on how to achieve this.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the id field in CosomosDB record... Is it the same all the time

Comment: If the answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Create a container with unique key using some unique field from the CSV file. After that you cannot add duplicate unique key values to Cosmos DB.

More info:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/unique-keys